# Limit with trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I compute $\lim_{x \to 1 } (\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2})^{cot^{2}\pi x}$?
So far I have got to this point $\lim_{x \to 1 }{cot^{2}\pi x}*\frac{\log_{}\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}}{\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}-1}*\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}-1$. I do not know how to continue with $\lim_{x \to 1 }{cot^{2}\pi x}*(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}-1)$.
Thank you

Comment: This limit does not exist, or more specifically it goes to infinity.

Comment: Well, according to solution in book, it should be equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi}$

Comment: Solution books can be wrong. Mathematica computes the limit as infinity. The way to see this is right is to note that $\cot^2(\pi x)$ goes to infinity as $x$ goes to 1. The other piece has a finite limit of 1 and so together they go to infinity.

Comment: But in WA I got the same answer http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28cotan%28pi*x%29%29%5E2*%28x%2F2%2B1%2F%282x%29-1%29+as+x+approaches+1

Comment: I think I see the problem. Is your $\cot^2(\pi x)$ in the exponent? I did not think it was an exponent. If that is the case Mathematics gives $\frac{1}{e^{2 \pi^2}}$ as the solution.

Comment: yes, I should have made it clear that I was in fact evaluating limit the way it is mentioned in answer below this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{Let }\displaystyle y=\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)^{\cot^2{\pi x}} \implies\ln y=\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\cos^2{\pi x}}{\sin^2\pi x}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)$$

Setting $x-1=h,$

$$\ln y=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos^2{\pi(h+1)}}{\sin^2\pi(h+1)}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{(h+1)^2+1}{2(h+1)}\right)$$

Now as $\displaystyle\frac{(h+1)^2+1}{2(h+1)}=1+\frac{h^2}{2(h+1)},$ 
 $\displaystyle \cos^2{\pi(h+1)}=\{\cos(\pi+\pi\cdot h)\}^2=\{-\cos(\pi\cdot h)\}^2=\cos^2(\pi\cdot h)$

Similarly,  $\displaystyle \sin^2{\pi(h+1)}=\sin^2(\pi\cdot h)$

using $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}u=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{v\to0}\frac{\sin  v}v=1,$

$\displaystyle\ln y$
$$=\left(\lim_{h\to0}\cos(\pi\cdot h)\right)^2\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{h^2}{2(h+1)}\right)}{\frac{h^2}{2(h+1)}}\cdot\frac1{\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi\cdot h)}{\pi \cdot h}\right)^2}\cdot\frac1{\lim_{h\to0}2(h+1)\pi^2}$$

$$\implies \ln y=1^2\cdot1\cdot\frac1{1^2}\cdot\frac1{2\pi^2}$$

$$\implies \ln y=e^{\frac1{2\pi^2}} $$

Comment: I was hoping for this kind of solution without having to use l'Hospital rule. Thank you, such solution is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The most important idea to remember: It is an exponential indeterminate form of the limit. Therefore it can be reduced to a multiplication indeterminate form of the limit by transforming the original exponential into one with constant basis. This can be done by using the identity $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$.

So, $(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2})^{cot^2(\pi x)}=e^{cot^2(\pi x)\ln(\frac{x+1/x}{2})}$.

Then it is enough to compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}cot^2(\pi x)\ln(\frac{x+1/x}{2})=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\cos^2(\pi x)}{\sin^2(\pi x)}\ln(\frac{x+1/x}{2})$

Since we know $\lim \cos^2(\pi x)$ it is enough to compute $\lim \frac{\ln(\frac{x+1/x}{2})}{\sin^2(\pi x)}$.

For this we could use L'Hospital's rule.

We compute $\lim \frac{\frac{2}{x+1/x}\frac{1-1/x^2}{2}}{2\pi\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)}=\lim \frac{\frac{x^2-1}{x^3+x^2}}{2\pi\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)}=-\frac{2}{\pi}\lim\frac{x-1}{\sin(\pi x)}$.

We can apply L'Hospital with this last again and compute $\lim \frac{1}{\cos(\pi x)\pi}=-\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Then, replacing this in the original limit, we get it is $e^{2/\pi^2}$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did, I got stuck at last limit you wrote. I started evaluating the limit by expanding it so I would get $\frac{\logy}{y-1}$, which should converge to 1, so then I am left with computing limit $\lim_{x \to 1 }{\frac{1}{sin^{2}\pi x}}*(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}-1)$ And I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Took me a while to go through what you did there, but I get it now. Thank you

Comment: @Karene, would mind comparing our solutions ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee They are clearly both correct. Or is it hard for you to see that a $2$ that was in a denominator that is now in a numerator is only a typo.